# Wildcard route is getting displayed along with every route

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I have two react modules `AppA` and `AppB`, under one single react app. Both of them have separate routing files, where I have defined the respective routes, specific to each of the modules. Under the main react project, I have a routing file, which combines routings from both the modules.

**appA-routing.tsx:**

```js
// All the require imports.

const AppARouting: FC = () => {
    /// TSX:
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path={"/appA"} element={<AppA_Layout />}>
                <Route path={Paths.appA_HOME} element={<AppA_Home />} >
                    <Route path={Paths.appA_DASHBOARD} element={<AppA_Dashboard />} />
                    <Route path={Paths.REQUESTS} element={<Requests />} />
                </Route>
        </Routes>
    );
};

AppA_Routing.displayName = "AppA_Routing";

export default AppA_Routing;
```

**appB-routing.tsx:**

```js
// All the require imports.

const AppBRouting: FC = () => {
    /// TSX:
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path={"/appB"} element={<AppB_Layout />}>
                <Route path={Paths.appB_HOME} element={<appB_Home />} >
                    <Route path={Paths.appB_DASHBOARD} element={<AppB_Dashboard />} />
                    <Route path={Paths.APPROVALS} element={<Approvals />} />
                </Route>
        </Routes>
    );
};

AppB_Routing.displayName = "AppB_Routing";

export default AppB_Routing;
```

**routing.tsx**

```js
// All the require imports.

const Routing: FC = () => {
    /// TSX:
    return (
        <BrowserRouter basename={Paths.BASE}>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<MainLayout />}>
                    <Route path="/" element={<MainHome />} />
                </Route>
            </Routes>

            <AppA_Routing />
            <AppB_Routing />

            <Routes>
                <Route path={Paths.SignOut} element={<SignOut />}/>
                <Route path={Paths.PAGE_NOT_FOUND} element={<UnknownRoute />} />
                <Route path="*" element={<UnknownRoute />} />
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
};

Routing.displayName = "Routing";

export default Routing;
```

The folder structure looks like below:

```
MainApp/
  |-src/
     |-common-components/
     |-modules/
     |  |-appA/
     |  |  |-appA-components/
     |  |  |-appA-routing.tsx
     |  |-appB/
     |     |-appB-components/
     |     |-appB-routing.tsx
     |-routing.tsx
```

I am facing one weird issue, when I am navigating to any particular route, it is loading it's respective component, but also along with that just below it is loading the wildcard route, that is `UnknownRoute` component too.

For example, if I am in `/appA/home` route, it is rendering like below:

```html
<AppA_Home />
<UnknownRoute /> <!-- The expected is, this component should not be loaded. -->
```

If I am in `/appB/home` route, it is rendering like below:

```html
<AppB_Home />
<UnknownRoute /> <!-- The expected is, this component should not be loaded. -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering all the sub-routes into separate `Routes` so they all get rendered/matched independently. Merge all the routes so that they are all rendered under a single `Routes` and can be rendered/matched as a combined group.

Example:

```
const Routing: FC = () => {
  /// TSX:
  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename={Paths.BASE}>
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<MainLayout />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<MainHome />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/appA/*" element={<AppARouting />} />
        <Route path="/appB/*" element={<AppBRouting />} />
        <Route path={Paths.SignOut} element={<SignOut />}/>
        <Route path={Paths.PAGE_NOT_FOUND} element={<UnknownRoute />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<UnknownRoute />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

The `AppARouting` and `AppBRouting` components render descendent routes that will be built relative to the parent route rendering them, so you may need to tweak the routes to get the sub-routes correct.

```
const AppARouting: FC = () => {
  /// TSX:
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<AppA_Layout />}> // <-- "/appA"
        <Route
          path={Paths.appA_HOME} // <-- "/appA/Paths.appA_HOME", etc
          element={<AppA_Home />}
        />
        <Route path={Paths.appA_DASHBOARD} element={<AppA_Dashboard />} />
        <Route path={Paths.REQUESTS} element={<Requests />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

```
const AppBRouting: FC = () => {
  /// TSX:
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route element={<AppB_Layout />}> // <-- "/appB"
        <Route path={Paths.appB_HOME} element={<appB_Home />} />
        <Route path={Paths.appB_DASHBOARD} element={<AppB_Dashboard />} />
        <Route path={Paths.APPROVALS} element={<Approvals />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

Comment: Without mentioning `<AppARouting />` and `<AppBRouting />` again, just below `</Routes>` its not rendering anything. Whenever I am going to a URL, I am getting `No routes matched location "URL"` warnings from `utils.ts:900` file in the console logs.

Comment: @ngShravil.py Think you could create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo/example of the code you are working with that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live, including exact reproduction steps?

Comment: Sure, it will take some time. Once done, I will post the link here.

Comment: @ngShravil.py Thanks, I think it will be very helpful to see a running code example.

Comment: FYI, the warning I am getting is coming from this location: `node_modules/@remix-run/router/utils.ts:900`.

Comment: @ngShravil.py The "No routes matched..." warning? Hopefully we can get that fixed  correctly from your running example.

Comment: Hey, here is the [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-lkfws6). I tried to repro the issue in a similar way. I have added a comment in `routing.tsx` file.

Comment: @ngShravil.py Update the sub-routes in the `AppARouting` to be similar to my answer and the apps work. By this I mean you should remove the `path={'/appA'}` layout route since it does *nothing* and change the `AppAHome` to be rendered simply on `"/"` instead of `"/appA/home"` since the matched URL path is already `"/appA"` from the `Routing` component. Just keep in mind that ***all*** descendent routes are *relative* to the parent route's path. If you need, I can update my answer to use path string literals instead of whatever these `Paths.<>` values might be to help make this more clear.

Comment: I cannot remove the `Layout` parts, because the layouts for both the apps are different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256953/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-ngshravil-py).